# Linear Speedup and Amdahl's law

Tags: computer-architecture

I'm having trouble understanding and solving the problem.

Suppose we have a program which is composed of 3 portions A, B and C and that each portion takes $t_A$, $t_B$ and $t_C$ respectively to run on a single-core CPU.

Assume that $t_A$ < $t_B$ < $t_C$

Assume we parallelize only the portion C of the code and that we run the whole program on a cluster that has up to $N$ cores. The speedup we achieve is linear to the number of cores.

I have to plot the execution time vs the number of cores

What I don't understand is, how can you have a linear speedup ? I've tried playing around with Amdahl's formula to find a way to have a linear speedup to the number of cores. I might be mistaken, but I've realized that this is only possible if the speedup is equal to the number of cores (so I don't understand how you can achieve a linear speedup).

If you could explain this to me, that would be very helpful, thank you.

Comment: I suggest forgetting for a minute about Amdahl's formula. If we parallelize $C$ perfectly, then its running time drops from $t_C$ to $t_C/N$. Therefore the total running time drops from $t_A+t_B+t_C$ to $t_A+t_B+t_C/N$.

Comment: I agree on that 100%. But how is the speedup linear to the number of cores ?

Comment: What you're suggesting I do, is simply plot $f(N) = t_A + t_B + t_C/N $, right?

Comment: That’s the meaning of linear speedup. You have N cores, the time drops by a factor of N.

Comment: Yes. Also, notice how Amdahl’s law is just a fancy name for the ratio of two quantities.

Comment: We achieve linear speedup for the C part, but no speedup for the rest. This is what Amdahl’s law is after - it’s a simple formula for the overall speedup in exactly this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase

> The speedup we achieve is linear to the number of cores.

refers only to the C portion of the program. Therefore the running time on $N$ cores is

$$ t_A + t_B + \frac{t_C}{N}. $$

The speedup is

$$
\frac{t_A + t_B + t_C}{t_A + t_B + t_C/N} =
\frac{1}{\frac{t_A + t_B + t_C/N}{t_A+t_B+t_C}} =
\frac{1}{\frac{t_A+t_B}{t_A+t_B+t_C}+\frac{1}{N} \frac{t_C}{t_A+t_B+t_C}}.
$$
This is Amdahl's law.